# Scilab to Find Roots of Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, scilab

How to determine the roots of differential function. I use `ode` to solve the function:

[image]

```
g=9.81//m/s^2
l=1.0//m
function phiprim=f(t,phi)
    phiprim(1)=phi(2)
    phiprim(2)=phi(1)*(-g/l)
endfunction
t0=0
tmax=%pi
step=0.05
t=t0:step:tmax
phi0=25/180*%pi // 25° in rad umgerechnet
phiprim0=0 // entspricht phi' bzw. Phi1'
phi=ode([phi0;phiprim0],t0,t,f)
```

[image]

So far, so good. But how can I determine the roots of `φ(t)` and `φ'(t)` in Scilab? 
Using `ode_root` function is throwing an error "invalid index":

```
deff("[z]=gr(t,phi)","z=phi(1)") // should find the roots of phi function
ng=1
[phi,rd]=ode("root",phi0,t0,tmax,f,ng,gr)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can interpolate the discrete solution and apply your favorite root finding algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ode` with root finding parameter. Here is the online doc but you can find it with `help ode_root`

https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/ode_root.html

Comment: I tried hard to implement the `ode_root` function:

    `deff("[z]=g(t,phi)","z=phi") // should find the roots of phi function
    ng=1
    [phi,rd]=ode("root",phi0,t0,t,f,ng,g)`

but all I get is a error message "invalid index". I have no idea how to adapt this to my 2nd order differential function.

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to find the zeros of phi ?

Comment: In your implementation `phi`has two components and the actual phi is `phi(1)`, I think you should write `deff("[z]=g(t,phi)","z=phi(1)")`.

Comment: yes, I looking for roots of phi. let me check your proposal...

Comment: I followed your proposal but I had no luck. I have no idea what to do now. The error message is followed by "ode: An error occurred in 'lsodar' subroutine." What is the `Isodar` subroutine?

Comment: You have a clash between `g`as 9.81 constant and `g`as function. Use another name for `g` as the constraint function, i.e. `gfun`.

Comment: Hello Stéphane, thanks for hanging on. You are right, I changed it. But I still have the issue and the same error message. I tried many things, but still no luck.

Comment: Your initial condition is wrong in the ode_root call. You have to use the same as the regular ode i.e. `[phi0;phiprim0]`, it is still a second order ode !

Comment: What the... That's it! Thank you so much. It is so obvious finally...